# "This is a pen." and "I am a boy." -- What are the equivalent sentences for Jp learners?

Tags: learning, jokes

http://ameblo.jp/uncle-joke-joke/entry-11613818795.html <--
This is a page making fun of "This is a pen." and "I am a boy."

These sentences have achieved legendary status.  For example, see :

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13142319713 --
> アニメ クレヨンしんちゃんで、風間くんが 「I am a boy. This is a pen.」 と繰り返し言っている回はなんと言う題名ですか？

> riki-english.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/12/01/222707 --  2015/12/01 - その昔、中学校に入ったばかりの1年生は、 I am a boy. とか、 This is a pen. とかいったような、いささかシュールなセンテンスから英語の勉強を始めたものでした。 今はもうこのような英文が授業で扱われることはまずありません。

My question is :  what are the equivalent sentences for Jp learners ?

( It's so common that most beginners encounter them, and/or the sentences seem so useless that it's funny. )

Comment: 「これは鉛筆です」 is the first sentence I ever learned.

Comment: for the longest time I thought it funny as well, until recently it struck me. If you know nothing of a language that is gramatically structured different, what better sentence than "this is a pen" SVO, no filler, no bending of the rules,  just pure, right to the point SVO.

Comment: @Mark Not to nitpick, but "This is a pen" is not a SVO sentence. It's a SVC sentence. It doesn't have any objects, but has a [subject complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)).

Comment: @marasai yeah, though it sure looks like an object when you see one ;)

Answer (score 2):

The following may be one:

> わたし は げんき です。

Or perhaps the whole phrase:

> はじめまして。わたしはnameです。どうぞよろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its just me, but every Japanese class I've ever taken always had "お名前は(insert name)です。” within the first week.

Comment: 「 **お**名前は(name)です」 for introducing yourself?

Comment: Actually, more like お名前は何ですか。Followed by お名前は(name)です。　Though I've always been told its more natural to respond with something like (name)です。　or formally (name)と呼んでいます。Does that help?

Comment: う～ん・・ちょっとわかんないんですけど。。自分の名前を聞かれたときの話ですよね？ I recommend using 「名前はXXです。"My name is XX."」(with no honorific prefix お) or「XXと呼**ばれ**ています。"I am called XX."」(using the passive form 呼ばれる)  when replying to お名前は何ですか？"What is your name?"

Answer (score 0):

The first things I ever learned (to speak), on the first day, were:

おはよう・おはようございます

A:　すみません。
B:　いいえ。

A:　分かりますか？
B:　ええ、分かります。

This was a number of years ago, so I'm only really sure about the above; but based on my old textbooks, I think I also learned the below:

The first week I think I learned other things like 違います and します and 今日, 明日 and　ね and よ.

Basically, I first learned affirming and negating (はい、いや等), a couple ritual expressions (おはよう), distal style verbal conjugation, sentence particles, and a couple other words I didn't quite understand at the time but soon learned were nominals.

I don't think I learned 私 for a couple weeks (probably around the time I learned about how to form nominal predicates).